# __exit__ decorator works but mypy complains "Too few arguments" at invocation

Tags: python, python-decorators, mypy

I've built an **exit** decorator to make sure that exception propagation gets handled consistently and correctly.

The decorator is working as designed, but I can't seem to make mypy completely happy. Here's the simplest example I've been able to construct:

```
import functools
from types import TracebackType
from typing import Callable, Optional as Opt, Type, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import Literal # pip install typing-extensions
import unittest

T = TypeVar ( 'T' )

EXITFUNC = Callable[
    [
        T,
        Opt[Type[BaseException]],
        Opt[BaseException],
        Opt[TracebackType],
    ],
    Literal[False]
]

class safe_exit:
    def __init__ ( self, exitfunc: EXITFUNC[T] ) -> None:
        self.exitfunc = exitfunc
    
    def __get__ ( self, obj: T, cls: Type[T] ) -> EXITFUNC[T]:
        @functools.wraps ( self.exitfunc )
        def safe_exit_wrapper (
            exc_type: Opt[Type[BaseException]],
            exc_val: Opt[BaseException],
            exc_tb: Opt[TracebackType],
        ) -> Literal[False]:
            try:
                return self.exitfunc ( obj, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb )
            except Exception:
                if not isinstance ( exc_val, Exception ):
                    raise
                return False
        return safe_exit_wrapper

class StrongException ( Exception ):
    pass

class WeakException ( BaseException ):
    pass

class ExitException ( Exception ):
    pass

class Foo:
    def __enter__ ( self ) -> 'Foo':
        return self
    
    @safe_exit
    def __exit__ ( self,
        exc_type: Opt[Type[BaseException]],
        exc_val: Opt[BaseException],
        exc_tb: Opt[TracebackType],
    ) -> Literal[False]:
        raise ExitException()
        return False

class Tests ( unittest.TestCase ):
    def test_exit_handling ( self ) -> None:
        
        foo = Foo()
        with self.assertRaises ( ExitException ):
            with foo: # <<< mypy error: Too few arguments
                pass
        
        with self.assertRaises ( ExitException ):
            with foo: # <<< mypy error: Too few arguments
                raise WeakException()
        
        with self.assertRaises ( StrongException ):
            with foo: # <<< mypy error: Too few arguments
                raise StrongException()

unittest.main()
```

The test runs successfully but mypy complains "error: Too few arguments" for every "with foo:"

No additional details. I've studied reveal_type and can't seem to find what the problem is.

Python 3.8.0
mypy 0.781

*EDIT* renamed callable to exitfunc to avoid confusion and fixed a typo

Comment: Why is your `safe_exit` a descriptor class instead of just a regular function-based decorator? It doesn't look like it needs to be a class.

Comment: because it's a decorator for a class method. If I create a regular function-based decorator I can't seem to get access to the object itself. I did try it, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: [Accessing `self` in a method decorator is straightforward.](https://ideone.com/NHctyL) It's the first argument to the method.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks that works, though it would be nice to figure out why mypy isn't happy with the class method in case that technique is useful to solve a future problem.

Comment: You've declared that your `__get__` returns `EXITFUNC[T]`, but it doesn't. `EXITFUNC[T]` takes a `T` as its first argument. (There are also some other annotation errors - for example, `__exit__` can return anything, not just `False` - and the whole idea of the way this decorator suppresses exceptions seems like it could cause problems.)

Comment: yes __exit__ can return anything, but this decorator isn't for *any* __exit__ function, just one that does resource cleanup, not try to swallow exceptions. The exception suppression that I'm doing is correct to the best of my knowledge. If the wrapped __exit__ throws an Exception we want to suppress it if exc_val is Exception but not if exc_val is None or a BaseException. In other words, if the exception thrown by the wrapped __exit__ is more serious than an exception already in flight, then we allow that exception, otherwise the exception already in flight takes precedence.

Comment: Almost all `__exit__` methods return `None`, though. Also, are you aware of [exception chaining](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/)? The default behavior preserves information about *both* exceptions, while your behavior loses information.

Comment: None is falsy. According to the python devs, if you don't plan to do anything about an exception in flight, the appropriate thing to do is return False, and they added warnings to mypy to that effect. I'm aware of exception chaining and appeciate the feature, but when an exception occurs in an __exit__ handler and there's already an exception in flight, I have found that the exception in the __exit__ handling is usually a side-effect of the exception already in flight and doesn't add useful information. That's my experience, but others' mileage may vary

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user2357112 I was able to figure out a solution that both works and keeps mypy happy.

Before I go into that solution, their suggestion of just using a method wrapper was the better solution:

```
EXITFUNC = Callable[
    [
        T,
        Opt[Type[BaseException]],
        Opt[BaseException],
        Opt[TracebackType],
    ],
    Literal[False]
]

def safe_exit ( exitfunc: EXITFUNC[T] ) -> EXITFUNC[T]:
    @functools.wraps ( exitfunc )
    def safe_exit_wrapper ( self: T,
        exc_type: Opt[Type[BaseException]],
        exc_val: Opt[BaseException],
        exc_tb: Opt[TracebackType],
    ) -> Literal[False]:
        try:
            return exitfunc ( self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb )
        except Exception:
            if not isinstance ( exc_val, Exception ):
                raise
            return False
    return safe_exit_wrapper
```

That being said, if for some reason you really *need* to do this as a class decorator for some reason, the trick I needed was 2 different EXITFUNC definitions, to whit:

```
import functools
from types import TracebackType
from typing import Callable, Optional as Opt, Type, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import Literal # pip install typing-extensions
import unittest

T = TypeVar ( 'T' )

EXITFUNC = Callable[
    [
        Opt[Type[BaseException]],
        Opt[BaseException],
        Opt[TracebackType],
    ],
    Literal[False]
]
EXITFUNCT = Callable[
    [
        T,
        Opt[Type[BaseException]],
        Opt[BaseException],
        Opt[TracebackType],
    ],
    Literal[False]
]

class safe_exit:
    def __init__ ( self, exitfunc: EXITFUNCT[T] ) -> None:
        self.exitfunc = exitfunc
    
    def __get__ ( self, obj: T, cls: Type[T] ) -> EXITFUNC:
        @functools.wraps ( self.exitfunc )
        def safe_exit_wrapper (
            exc_type: Opt[Type[BaseException]],
            exc_val: Opt[BaseException],
            exc_tb: Opt[TracebackType],
        ) -> Literal[False]:
            try:
                return self.exitfunc ( obj, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb )
            except Exception:
                if not isinstance ( exc_val, Exception ):
                    raise
                return False
        return safe_exit_wrapper

class StrongException ( Exception ):
    pass

class WeakException ( BaseException ):
    pass

class ExitException ( Exception ):
    pass

class Foo:
    def __enter__ ( self ) -> 'Foo':
        return self
    
    @safe_exit
    def __exit__ ( self,
        exc_type: Opt[Type[BaseException]],
        exc_val: Opt[BaseException],
        exc_tb: Opt[TracebackType],
    ) -> Literal[False]:
        raise ExitException()
        return False

class Tests ( unittest.TestCase ):
    def test_exit_handling ( self ) -> None:
        
        foo = Foo()
        with self.assertRaises ( ExitException ):
            with foo:
                pass
        
        with self.assertRaises ( ExitException ):
            with foo:
                raise WeakException()
        
        with self.assertRaises ( StrongException ):
            with foo:
                raise StrongException()

unittest.main()
```